# Is there a way to query NetSuite tables to tell if an invoice has been emailed

Tags: netsuite

I am writing some code to integrate with our installation of NetSuite. We use a service by CData to replicate the primary NetSuite tables down to our local SQL Server. My code will send an electronic invoice (outside of NetSuite) but I don't want to send it if it has already been emailed from within NetSuite using their built in feature.
The "Invoice" table contains all the main header info for invoices and there is an "Email" column in there. If that field has a value in it does that mean the invoice has been emailed? Or can someone fill in that field WITHOUT emailing the invoice? (I need to know if the invoice has in fact been sent)

Answer (score 0):

The email column should be the email on the communication sub tab.

You can see if an invoice has been sent the "Message" sub tab in communication.  If the record in there is a type = "email" then the message has been sent through Netsuite's internal functionality.

Does that help?  Also, can I ask if you were successful with this?  I am also looking to send emails using a CData connection.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a status that would indicate if the invoice had been printed or not. Didn't find it. The solution could be to build a custom field on the transaction called 'Print status'. It would be a drop down list with 3 possible values: Pending, Printed Original and Printed copy. Set the field to 'Disabled' and its default value as 'Pending'.

We could go further and add a custom field called 'Date last printed' and even a 'Last printed by'.

Then we can build a workflow of action type 'Set field value', the condition of Field value = 'Pending' and an action to set the 'Print status' to 'Printed original' once the invoice is first printed.

A second action to set it to 'Printed copy' if someone reprints the invoice.
Using 'Set field value, we can also chane the transaction form to one that points to a pdf template with 'COPY' on it.

My issue is that the standard Action, Print of the invoice does not trigger any action on the workflow. So I guess we should look into building this via script.

Let me know if you find an easy workflow alternative.

Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).